# Wireless adapter turns off at low battery, but system is not allowed to turn it off to save power

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, multi-boot, power-management, ubuntu-16.04

Currently running a Windows 10/Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot with GRUB boot loader. When I'm on windows, after the battery hits 50% the wireless adapter becomes disabled and doesn't appear in device manager. After charging back above 75% and doing a full shutdown, they adapter turns back on (and is visible in device manager once more.) Under device properties, the checkbox is unchecked to allow the computer to turn off the device to save power.

Comment: "When I'm on Windows" is not "only when I'm on Windows". What happens on Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu has no problems. After the device turns off on windows, it will fail to work on ubuntu as well, until windows turns it back on again.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help you with Windows (I use Linux far more than Windows) but still we can do some research. When it happens, what's the output of `rfkill list all` in Ubuntu? Does `sudo rfkill unblock all` turn the adapter back on?

Comment: `rfkill list all` found my bluetooth adapters (which remain unchanged), but not the wireless adapter. Unblocking does nothing. In light of this, I suspect that my original theory may be incorrect, and that it may be some form of hardware issue? The other day the adapter was disabled even when I was at 80% battery.